# onepage checkout order successful page is blank no errors

Tags: onepage-checkout

[image]

1. Already increased php memomry.

Comment: I assume there will be errors either in the exception.log, system.log more likely in the Apache error log file

Comment: Please share  code of this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First check that log settings are ON or not. To check:
   Go to System >> Configuration then Click on developer link in left menu.
   Open log settings section and set Enabled to "Yes", then save setting.

   Now check `/var/log` folder after revisiting page.
2. Also you can modify your website's `index.php` and change:

   ```
   if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {

       Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
   }

   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ```

   to

   ```
   //if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
       Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
   //}

   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ```

When you check the page again and there is any php error, warning or notice; you can see it on browser screen.

I hope it will help you in finding cause of problem.

Comment: here is the error:-
Notice: Undefined variable: _options  in /var/www/vhosts/shoppynshop.com/shoppynshop.com/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/verify.phtml on line 4

#0 /var/www/vhosts/shoppynshop.com/shoppynshop.com/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/verify.phtml(4): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 4, Array)
#

Answer (score 2):

Blank page usually means a php fatal error

You'd check both application logs (Magento /var/log & /var/report folders) and system logs (/var/log/apache2/error.log or the webserver you're using) to see the concrete error

Nobody could help you without the concrete error info

Answer (score -1):

This is done. thanks to Raul Sanchez.

This was a conflict from another onepage checkout(gfs checkout).

Comment: Glad it helped. As Qaisar commented, you'd accept the answer as valid, as that's how this site works, reputation, etc...